# kylin with hive client mode can not accessing the remote database

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, hbase, kylin

I'm trying to deploy Apache Kylin on the client node, and I have installed hive, hbase, Hadoop, on the client machine.

I'm able to create the database from client hive CLI mode to HDFS, but it didn't show the database when I run the command: show databases;

I have successfully started the Kylin (through the command: *$KYLIN_HOME/bin/Kylin.sh start*).

But when I try to run the command ( *$KYLIN_HOME/bin/sample.sh* ) for creating a sample cube it through an error: ***FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: DEFAULT***

here is a snapshot of command: $KYLIN_HOME/bin/sample.sh
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75FYw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it didn't show the database when I run the command: show databases;

If so it means that you don't have any databases in Hive at all. Try to create a database first.